# Filter a dataframe using a list of tuples in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to filter a dataframe in scala by comparing two of its columns (subject and stream in this case) to a list of tuples. If the column values and the tuple values are equal the row is filtered.

```
val df = Seq(
  (0, "Mark", "Maths", "Science"),
  (1, "Tyson", "History", "Commerce"),
  (2, "Gerald", "Maths", "Science"),
  (3, "Katie", "Maths", "Commerce"),
  (4, "Linda", "History", "Science")).toDF("id", "name", "subject", "stream")
```

Sample input:

```
+---+------+-------+--------+
| id|  name|subject|  stream|
+---+------+-------+--------+
|  0|  Mark|  Maths| Science|
|  1| Tyson|History|Commerce|
|  2|Gerald|  Maths| Science|
|  3| Katie|  Maths|Commerce|
|  4| Linda|History| Science|
+---+------+-------+--------+
```

List of tuple based on which the above df needs to be filtered

```
  val listOfTuples = List[(String, String)] (
    ("Maths" , "Science"),
    ("History" , "Commerce")
)
```

Expected result :

```
+---+------+-------+--------+
| id|  name|subject|  stream|
+---+------+-------+--------+
|  0|  Mark|  Maths| Science|
|  1| Tyson|History|Commerce|
|  2|Gerald|  Maths| Science|
+---+------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do it with `isin` with structs (needs spark 2.2+):

```
val df_filtered = df
    .where(struct($"subject",$"stream").isin(listOfTuples.map(typedLit(_)):_*))
```

or with leftsemi join:

```
val df_filtered = df
.join(listOfTuples.toDF("subject","stream"),Seq("subject","stream"),"leftsemi")
```

Comment: Nice solutions.  According to the Spark API doc, [`isin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@isin(list:Any*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) should be available since Spark1.5+.

Comment: @Leo C yes, but typedLit is available since spark 2.2

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `filter` as

```
val resultDF = df.filter(row => {
  List(
    ("Maths", "Science"),
    ("History", "Commerce")
  ).contains(
    (row.getAs[String]("subject"), row.getAs[String]("stream")))
})
```

Hope this helps!